# Master branch won't pull updates from local branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-pull

I created a branch using these commands "git branch placeorder" in my terminal locally, and it was created successfully but when I had committed and pushed my changes, they were not overwritten in my master branch. When I went on Github I saw that I had a branch and a pull request so I thought let me pull the changes but that causes some complications and I decided to delete the branch from github. I still have access to the branch locally but when I try to do "git pull" in the terminal while on the master branch it won´t overwrite my updates and says that my branch is already up to date. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `merge` your placeorder branch into your master branch.

First `git checkout master` to assure you are in master branch;

Then `git merge placeorder` to perform the merge.

You can find more information about merge in git documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)